# Is there some place where I can suggest a firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I have an idea. It would be great if I could communicate that to someone interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check at the [Mozillazine forums](http://forums-test.mozillazine.org/).
Another place to look at would be the [Mozilla Wishlist group](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.wishlist).

Comment: though I feel there should be an official "Mozilla Suggestion" page.